# Windows time zone automatically sets itself to Pacific, and it doesn't change

Tags: windows-10, time-zone

My Windows time zone is permanently set to Pacific time even though I'm in EST zone. I have turned off "Set time automatically", "Set time zone automatically" and even when I change the time zone to EST, it just reverts back to Pacific time. When I attempt to try and change the time zone, it tells me that I am unable to perform the task, even though I am the only person using my computer, and I am an administrator.

[image: Errors ouch]

Comment: Please provide us the appropriate section within Settings.  It appears your system is under the control of a group policy.  If that is the case you will be unable to change the time zone on the machine.  **You should contact your system Administrator for assistance in this matter.**

Comment: Are you using a VPN? Does this computer belong to a company and is managed by a domain or other enterprise computer management tool?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're an administrator, it may be that the Date and Time settings are running without admin permissions.

Try running `timedate.cpl` as administrator, then you should be able to make the change.